# Eclipse 06-2023, Importing swt. sdk example to run it?

Tags: eclipse, installation, swt

I have Eclipse 06-2023 running on Windows 10 Home.
I had downloaded the swt examples view 3.107.100... and swt example view source 3.108... jar files and imported them into my workspace via file->import

Since I couldn't get the examples to run, I tried these instructions at,
[Installing the examples](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fsamples%2Forg.eclipse.swt.examples%2Fdoc-html%2Fswt_manual_setup.html)
However, when I get to the install popup and accept all the trusted sites shown and the license, the "install" remains greyed out and can't go any further and have to select the cancel button.
I guess it sees that I already have it installed in my workspace by seeing that its the same version. and the jar file I had installed via file->import also shows up in the .p2/pool/plugin directory

If I continue following the steps to verify their installation per the instructions,

"You can verify that examples have been installed by looking for File > New > Example... in the workbench menu bar."
Nothing is shown for the swt examples for me to test them out.

How do I fix this issue so that I can run the examples to see what they do?

Comment: Screenshots are good and useful sometimes.

Comment: There are several ways to download and run the SWT examples. Did you follow https://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php#insideEclipse ? The following worked for me: in _Help > Install New Software..._ work with the update site [`https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.28/`](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.28/) to install _Eclipse SDK Examples_. Restart Eclipse and in _Window > Show View > Other..._ choose e.g. _SWT Examples > SWT Controls_.